# Can I go from Warsaw to Lisbon by bus without border check?

Tags: schengen, borders

I have a Poland national visa and I want to go Lisbon for one week, but I'm scared to go there because nowadays Polish border guards are too strict. So tell me how can I go?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Are you asking on how to avoid the border check on the Polish border? Does your visa allow you to go to Portugal or are you trying to sneak in?

Comment: Yes, are you seeking to find a more practical way to lawfully travel to Portugal and back, or do you have visa issues that would prevent this?

Comment: @drat national visas of Schengen countries allow their bearers to visit all other Schengen countries.

Comment: In what way are the guards 'too strict'? Are you frightened they won't let you leave, or are you worried they won't let you return? If you have a valid visa they have no reason to bother you. You __do__ have a valid visa?

Comment: I'm closing this as unclear since I am under the impression that you are asking us for advice on how to break the law. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 6):

Taking the bus is not a good way to avoid controls. Wether you're worried about the unpleasantness or inconvenience of controls or if you're worried you're bending the rules of a visa, taking the bus is probably not the best mode of travel, it seems likely that you'll experience a higher level of scrutiny by taking the bus than other modes.

In this [TV report about human trafficking (in German)](https://youtu.be/PwKtsHmH9Iw?t=1m21s) you'll notice how the German police systematically stop buses near the border. The first group people they stop have valid Lithuanian tourist visas, still they're hauled off the bus and into a police station where they're deemed to be abusing the visas because they only stayed in Lithuania for one day and they aren't carrying cash when the stated purpose of their tourist visa was to buy a used car.

Even at the height of the open borders before the influx of refugees in 2015, scheduled buses were targeted for "random" internal controls inside the Schengen area. During this time I once crossed Germany by bus: we were stopped four separate times in one night by various German police for "random" passport checks. Across the EU, I've experienced the same "random" checks more often when travelling by bus that by any other mode. I've experienced this Czechia, Austria, Germany, France and Belgium.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Germany's internal foreigner checks

Answer (score 2):

France has introduced spot checks at the land border, and German police perform internal foreigner checks on buses fairly often.

Just fly! You will **definitely** not face any border checks that way, and if **not** taking Ryanair, easyJet or Wizz **and** only having hand luggage, you will not normally be asked for any ID by check-in staff.

Comment: Surely other airlines check ID at the gate? That's what happens on domestic flights in the UK, I seem to remember...

Comment: @jacoman891 UK is not in Schengen, after all... are they still in EU? ;)

Comment: @Kamil, I'm aware of that, but I'm talking about domestic flights. Aren't intra-Schengen flights simply treated as domestic? I can't imagine that you could turn up to the airport with just a boarding pass and get on a plane.

Comment: and in general, ID checks on the airports depend on the airport, on smaller ones (like KRK), there is someone actually checking your ID when going onboard, but for example in Oslo-Gardermoen, everything relies on scanners of QR codes on a boarding pass (even if you have registered luggage)

Comment: @jacoman891 - you should go to Oslo :) that's exactly the case there

Comment: @jacoman891 "I can't imagine that you could turn up to the airport with just a boarding pass and get on a plane" I do that a lot flying from Switzerland to Germany, Spain, Sweden, Poland or Greece. Even lost my ID in Berlin once and got home to Zurich with zero issues